# ExtJs Combobox displayField encoding

Tags: java, javascript, html, extjs, encoding

I have a java web application. I have an entity class which (after transformation of course) i would like to use in a combobox with ExtJs. My problem is as follows:

There can be entries having html code in the displayField. Because of that during the serialization with flexjson.JSONSerializer i used the flexjson.HTMLEncoder to make the entries visible in the dropdown (before it made the screen died because of unterminated String literal). So far so good.

```
editor.myCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode: 'local',
    editable: false,
    forceSelection: true,           
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['myId', 'myName'],
        emptyItem: {'myName' : '...'},
        data: <c:out value="${form.json['myList']}" escapeXml="false"/>         
    }),
    disabled: isEditorDisabled,
    width: 75,
    listWidth: 160,
    displayField: 'myName',
    valueField: 'myId'
});
```

But when i select an item from the dropdown (all displayed properly like `Alfred </script>`) the display field will show it as: `Alfred &lt;/script&gt;`.

How do i make this work? Why it is showing the encoded version (that is retrieved on the json request) and not as HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including an overridden `getDisplayValue` method in your config. Just set it up to return the decoded value, like this:

```
editor.myCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode: 'local',
    editable: false,
    forceSelection: true,           
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['myId', 'myName'],
        emptyItem: {'myName' : '...'},
        data: <c:out value="${form.json['myList']}" escapeXml="false"/>         
    }),
    disabled: isEditorDisabled,
    width: 75,
    listWidth: 160,
    displayField: 'myName',
    valueField: 'myId',

    // this should return the decoded string instead
    getDisplayValue: function() {
        return Ext.String.htmlDecode(this.value);
    }
});
```

The reason it has to be done this way is because the actual field part of the  `Ext.form.field.Combo` really is an HTML input element and that will only display the straight text, it will not generate the HTML from it.

Comment: Suggested solution doesn't work in version 4.x (didnt tested in older versions) - combo always displays decoded value from valueField instead of decoded value of displayField.
To make it work, replace method body with:
`return Ext.String.htmlDecode(this.displayTpl.apply(this.displayTplData));`